# Support for script type="text/babel" in Visual Studio Code

Tags: javascript, babeljs, visual-studio-code

When I'm editing the below example HTML page in Visual Studio Code (borrowed from Facebook's React tutorial and slightly edited), if I write any Javascript code in the script block, it is *not* syntax highlighted. But if I change the script block type to "text/javascript" then the syntax highlighting works. But then any React-y/JSX code doesn't work as it is wired to work through Babel.

Is there any way to have the script tag "type" attribute set to "text/babel" and at the same time have proper syntax highlighting in Visual Studio Code?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>React Tutorial</title>
    <script src="https://npmcdn.com/react@15.3.0/dist/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://npmcdn.com/react-dom@15.3.0/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://npmcdn.com/babel-core@5.8.38/browser.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://npmcdn.com/jquery@3.1.0/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://npmcdn.com/remarkable@1.6.2/dist/remarkable.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <script type="text/babel">
      ReactDOM.render(
        <div>Hello world!</div>,
        document.getElementById('content')
      );
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to this now.

Open up: `(VS code home dir)\resources\app\extensions\html\syntaxes\html.json`, and edit the regex for the script tag. That fixed the issue for me.

Comment: This is the line `"end": "(?i:(?=/?>|type\\s*=\\s*('|\"|)(?!text/(javascript|ecmascript|babel)|application/((x-)?javascript|ecmascript|babel))\\b))",`

Comment: This needs more info.  For instance, what line is the "script" tag line? There appears to be multiple.  Also, it's unclear if this fixes the issue caused by Babel JavaScript as described here: https://github.com/dracula/visual-studio-code/issues/76

Answer (score 0):

Well this is a workaround, probably will be better to change this in a post build process, but I found an easy way to do it with this new feature **TagHelpers** which will help to replace the *javascript* value by *babel*

So add a file **TagHelpers/ScriptTagHelper.cs**

```
[HtmlTargetElement("script", Attributes = "to_babel")]
public class ScriptTagHelper : TagHelper
{
   public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
   {
       output.Attributes.SetAttribute("type", "text/babel");
   }
}
```

In your page **Index.cshtml**

```
<script type="text/javascript" to_babel>
```

And dont forget to import TagHelpers in **_ViewImports.cshtml** or in your **Index.cshtml**

```
@using app1
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@addTagHelper *, app1
```

And voila! this render as babel.

Comment: Read the question again. It's about syntax highlighting in Visual Studio Code, not ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: yes, what i am saying is you can keep it as `text/javascript` to have highlighting, and process it later to change to babel, in my workaournd i am using asp.net, you can use any other tool.