# Visual Studio Code: Auto complete HTML tags inside an embedded babel script

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, visual-studio-code, babeljs

I have an html file with an embedded babel script within it

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>React tutorial</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.2/browser.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script type="text/babel">

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I would like it be the case that when I'm typing inside the babel script

```
    <script type="text/babel">

    </script>
```

And I type something like `<div>` the software autocompletes the end tag by entering the text `</div>` in

---

Neither the [auto close tag](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.auto-close-tag) extension, nor the [sublime babel extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=joshpeng.sublime-babel-vscode), from the visual studio marketplace, was able to do this.

I also followed the advice of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39320393/jsx-or-html-autocompletion-in-visual-studio-code) and created a file named `.vscode/settings.json` which contains

```
"emmet.includeLanguages": {
    "javascript": "javascriptreact"
},
"emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true
"emmet.includeLanguages": {
    "javascript": "html"
}
```

And this also had no effect.

Comment: It might be a stupid question, but "why?". If you're only going for the React tutorial you don't have to use babel, because most modern browsers already have the features needed by React. Therefore there's no need to transpile.

Comment: @MichałKostrzyński Because I'm using babel

Comment: Alright, scratch what I said - I forgot about JSX not being properly handled without babel when using inline script tag. 
Either way - the reason VSCode doesn't get that kind of setup is probably because nobody is doing it that. If you want to learn React, using the create-react-app is probably going to be both easier and more comfortable (because of all the hot reload stuff).

Comment: @MichałKostrzyński Why is create-react-app better? I'm pretty sure I used it when going through reacts intro tutorial https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html, and seems like it's just way easier to include those three scripts(including babel) in my header.

Answer (score 4):

[image: VS Code]

It worked on me. Are you sure you did everything right?

[image: Emmet HTML]

```
{
    "emmet.includeLanguages": {
        "javascript": "html"
     }
}
```

Can you remove the file and add it again?
Just what I threw.

Source :

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/html

https://docs.emmet.io/cheat-sheet/

Comment: Specifically within the babel script. As in within <script type="text/babel">

    </script>

Comment: Please don't include images of code, include code as text correctly formatted (use the `{}` button in the editor. Pictures of code can not be copied and pasted.

Answer (score 1):

[javascript - Support for script type="text/babel" in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40134106/11588298)

Maybe you want look at, this issue is previously discussed and resolved. As for my thoughts, VS Code using regex for intellisense and when I looked at these regex codes, I was already seeing babel but it didn't work in a meaningless way for me too.

Comment: So there's a comment on the answer which says "This needs more info. For instance, what line is the "script" tag line? There appears to be multiple". Do you think you're able to answer this question.